# How to pass command line arguments to FFMpeg in iOS

Tags: ios, ffmpeg

This is a beginner question, since I am new to iOS(I started it today), so please pardon my ignorance and lack of iOS knowledge.

After building and successfully using FFMpeg for Android I wanted to do the same for iOS.
So I built FFMpeg successfully for iOS by following this [link](https://github.com/lajos/iFrameExtractor), but after all that pain I am confused as how to use FFMpeg in iOS, I mean how can I pass command line arguments to `libffmpeg.a` file?

I am assuming that there must be a way to run the .a file as an executable and then pass command line arguments and hope for FFMpeg to do the magic, I did the same in Android and it worked beautifully.

I am also aware that I can use ffmpeg.c class and use its main method, but the question remains; how do I pass those command line arguments?

Is there something I am supposed to be aware of here, is the thing what I am doing now correct or am I falling short on my approach?

I wanted to mix two audio files, so the command for doing that would be `ffmpeg -i firstSound.wav -i secondSound.wav -filter_complex amix=inputs=2:duration=longest finalOutput.wav`, how do I do the same in iOS?

Can someone please shed some light on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't pass arguments to a .a file as it's a library file. It's something you build your application with, giving you access to the functions provided by the ffmpeg library. I'm not sure what the state of play with Android is but it's likely it's generating a command line executable instead.

Have a look at the ffmpeg documentation, there's probably a way to do what you want with the library, however building and running ffmpeg as a standalone, pass-in-arguments, binary is unlikely.

Comment: So there is no handler in ffmpeg.c class that can take in command line arguments?

Comment: No, the ffmpeg.c file is essentially a source file, libraries don't take arguments they just provide functionality. What you have on Android is very likely a binary of ffmpeg, what you have here is a library. An .a file is a `static library`, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_library

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in your `main.c`, and of course you wouldn't hardcode args these are just for illustration

I assume your using `ffmpeg` for playback since your playing with `iframeextractor`, what actually is the goal of what your trying to do.

```
/* Called from the main */
int main(int argc, char **argv)

int flags, i;
/*
argv[1] = "-fs";
argv[2] = "-skipframe";
argv[3] = "30";
argv[4] = "-fast";
argv[5] = "-sync";
argv[6] = "video";
argv[7] = "-drp";
argv[8] = "-skipidct";
argv[9] = "10";
argv[10] = "-skiploop";
argv[11] = "50";
argv[12] = "-threads";
argv[13] = "5";
//argv[14] = "-an";
argv[15] = "http://172.16.1.33:63478/hulu-f4fa0821-767a-490a-8cb5-f03788760e31/1-hulu-f4fa0821-767a-490a-8cb5-f03788760e31.mpg";
argc += 14;
*/


/* register all codecs, demux and protocols */
avcodec_register_all();
avdevice_register_all();
av_register_all();


parse_options(argc, argv, options, opt_input_file);

. .. mo
}
```

Comment: also look at this to see how to call  https://github.com/mooncatventures-group/RTSPPlay/blob/master/uikit/SDL_uikitappdelegate.m

Comment: I want to mix two audio or video files, I have a command for that but was not sure of how to do it in iOS

Comment: Probably wouldn't use ffmpeg to mix audio files in iOS , audio toolbox api in iOS is much better for that, decode both streams separately and define an audio unit. see the audio mixer example on the apple portal.As for video mixing, IOS supports standard c calling conventions, but you need to use the static ffmpeg libs like  we did with the player.

Comment: @MichelleCannon That is mean i can not use ffmpeg command on ios device ??